# Evaluate the following inverse trigonometric summation:

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{2n^{2}}\right)
$$
I have tried to approach the problem by a telescopic series,
$$
\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{1+2 n^{2}-1}\right)
$$ but after factorizing the denominator like this, $$
\begin{array}{r}
(n \sqrt{2}+1)(n \sqrt{2}-1) \\
=\left(2 n^{2}-1\right)
\end{array}
$$
and subtracting the factors, I am left with 2 as the difference which prohibits me from using $\arctan(a)-\arctan(b)$ formula, please help.

Comment: Does $\tan^{-1}(x) = \tanh(x)$

Comment: You may try $$\frac{1}{2n^2}=\frac{(2n+1)-(2n-1)}{1+(2n+1)(2n-1)}. $$

Answer (score 4):

You should notice that
$$\arctan{\left(\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)}=\arctan{\left(2n+1\right)}-\arctan{\left(2n-1\right)}$$
Therefore the series is telescopic and you're left with:
$$-\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2}=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let;
$$S= \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}arctan \left(\frac{1}{2r^2}\right)$$

To telescope the series, we need to align the format to $arctan\left(\frac{a-b}{1+ab}\right)$,

$$S= \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}arctan \left(\frac{2}{1+4r^2-1}\right)$$

$$S= \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}arctan \left(\frac{2}{1+(2r-1)(2r+1)}\right)$$

$$S= \sum_{r=1}^{n} arctan (2r-1)-arctan(2r+1)$$

$$S=\frac{\pi}{4}-arctan(2n+1)$$

Now as n tends to $\infty$ you get;
$$S=\frac{\pi}{4}$$